# AutoMapper execute function to replace the source object

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have this class:

```
public class Policy
{
    // some members
   
    public Policy GetEffective()
    {
          // run some logic
          return mergedPolicy;
    }
}
```

I want to use AutoMapper to map objects of this type to another type, but before mapping them, then call this method and **replace** the source with the returned object from this method.

I tried to use the `BeforeMap` method but it doens't seem to work on the whole source, just on the source members.

```
 CreateMap<Policy, PolicyResponse>()
                .BeforeMap((src, dest) => src = src.GetEffective());
```

Comment: Sorry, may not provide you the answer. Based on what I see in doc, the BeforeMap & AfterMap action is used for custom logic to assign value to single property only. I don't see any example that can directly override the `src`. And seems no other method that allow you to do as what you desired. Like `.ConstructUsing()`, `.ConvertUsing()`, but this requires you to implement the mapping logic. So, you should do it without AutoMapper.

Comment: I might miss the point here but it feels like hiding to much in the mapper and doing something unexpected for someone only seeing the mapper call. A simple `source = mapper.Map(source)`  should do and looks understandable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just map the result of `GetEffective`

```
_mapper.Map<PolicyResponse>(policy.GetEffective());
```

###### Update:

In order to get the mapping to call `GetEffective` I would suggest making `GetEffective` return a different type. Create a mapping profile for the return type of `GetEffective` to `PolicyResponse` then use `ConstructUsing` in the definition of the mapping for `Policy` to `PolicyResponse`:

```
CreateMap<EffectivePolicy, PolicyResponse>();
 
CreateMap<Policy, PolicyResponse>()
   .ConstructUsing((policy, context) => context.Mapper.Map<PolicyResponse>(policy.GetEffective(policy)));
```

Comment: That would work for one, but in my case I need to map an array of `Policy` to an array of `PolicyResponse` like: `_mapper.Map<PolicyResponse[]>(policies)`. I know I can iterate over `policies` and change them to the result of `GetEffective`, but I was wondering if there's a way to achieve this with AutoMapper to make things a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround that could work for you using Reflection to assign the values to the **src**.

```
CreateMap<c1, c2>()
    .BeforeMap((src, dest) =>
    {
        var effective= src.GetEffective();
        var props = effective.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props)
            prop.SetValue(src, prop.GetValue(effective));
    });
```